# How to show SQL query formed by ::create Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to display a ready formed SQL after operation:

```
 $r = \App\Visitor::create($item);
```

Where `$item` is array data.

I wonder why this operation returns in `$r` inserted model, but there is no changes in db table.

So, thanks for answers I tried yours solutions:

**This is query:**

```
insert into `visitors` (`lastname`, `firstname`, `middlename`, `birthday`, `company`, `document_number`, `pincode`, `code`, `idEvent`) values ("Huse", "Huseynkhanov", "Akif", "1981-04-09", "XXX", 16428285, "QT0FE12", 19283746564923, "17");
```

**This is screen of binding:**

[image]

If execute query above in database it works. But Laravel does not insert data.

**Model is:**

```
class Visitor extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public $table = 'visitors';

    protected $fillable = [
        "lastname",
        "firstname",
        "middlename",
        "birthday",
        "company",
        "document_number",
        "pincode",
        "status",
        "code",
        "idEvent"
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'idVisitor';

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new StatusScope);
    }
}
```

**Code is:**

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    \App\Visitor::create($item);
}
```

Comment: please be specific. do you want the sql query that preformed to insert data?

Comment: Sure, user below have answered and have got my issue

Comment: yes that's correct. looks like I replied too late to your question :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, you can do something like this:

```
$r = \App\Visitor::create($item)->toSql();
dd($r);
```

Comment: Very strange but it gives me SELECT query instead INSERT: `"select * from `visitors` where `status` = ?"`

Comment: You can either try wigh the Davit's answer, or running with debugbar. 
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
\App\Visitor::create(['key' => 'value', ....]);
$data = DB::getQueryLog();
$query = str_replace(array_fill(0, count($data[0]['bindings']), '?'), $data[0]['bindings'],  $data[0]['query']);
dd($query);
```

Comment: What is a problem?? Show `$item` value

Comment: See my question please

Comment: Are you use transactions??

Comment: What does it mean? I use `::create` in loop

Comment: See https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#database-transactions. Also can you show your whole code?

Comment: No I dont use transactions